# Python P2P sockets error "This operation would block forever"

Tags: python, sockets, p2p, python-multithreading, gevent

Hello I'm trying to create a P2P program to distribute messages throgh the clients.

My server.py:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import logging
from daemon import Daemon
import time
import argparse
import sys
from transaction import Transaction
import settings
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = '139.59.26.12'
bind_port = 9998

my_node_addr = str(bind_ip) + ":" + str(bind_port)

clients = [("0.0.0.0", 9999), ("0.0.0.0", 9998)]

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(5)  # max backlog of connections

print('Listening on {}:{}'.format(bind_ip, bind_port))

numbers = []

def broadcast_info(info):
    for n in clients:
        node_str_addr = str(n[0]) + ":" + str(n[1])
        print("Selected: " + node_str_addr)
        if node_str_addr != my_node_addr:
            client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            client.connect((n[0], n[1]))
            client.send(info)
            response = client.recv(4096)

def handle_client_connection(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    request_str = request.decode()
    if request_str == 'print':
        client_socket.send(str(numbers).encode('utf-8'))
        print(numbers)
    else:
        client_socket.send('Added!'.encode('utf-8'))
        client_socket.close()
        num_rec = int(request.decode())
        if num_rec not in numbers:
            numbers.append(num_rec)
            #broadcast_info(request)

while True:
    client_sock, address = server.accept()
    print('Accepted connection from {}:{}'.format(address[0], address[1]))
    client_handler = threading.Thread(
        target=handle_client_connection,
        args=(client_sock,)
        # without comma you'd get a... TypeError: handle_client_connection() argument after * must be a sequence, not _socketobject
    )
    client_handler.start()
```

And my client:

```
import socket

hostname, sld, tld, port = 'www', 'integralist', 'co.uk', 80
target = '{}.{}.{}'.format(hostname, sld, tld)

# create an ipv4 (AF_INET) socket object using the tcp protocol (SOCK_STREAM)
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# connect the client
# client.connect((target, port))
client.connect(('139.59.76.32', 9998))

# send some data (in this case a HTTP GET request)
client.send("2".encode('utf-8'))  # Number or "print"

# receive the response data (4096 is recommended buffer size)
response = client.recv(4096)

print (response)

client.close()
```

Sometimes it works well. But then after a few tries this error appears:

```
Exception in thread Thread-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "server.py", line 43, in handle_client_connection
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 336, in recv
    self._wait(self._read_event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 156, in _wait
    self.hub.wait(watcher)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 651, in wait
    result = waiter.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 898, in get
    return self.hub.switch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 630, in switch
    return RawGreenlet.switch(self)
gevent.hub.LoopExit: ('This operation would block forever', <Hub at 0x7fdf21aa2af8 epoll pending=0 ref=0 fileno=9>)
```

I tried everything. In my local machine works fine. But when I try to do it on my Digitalocean VPS, then this happens. I've search about this error over the Internet but I can't find anything that helps me.

Do you know what can be the cause of this error?

Thanks